# Easiest way to run a batch job every 5 minutes in Rails 3 with Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, batch-file, cron, heroku

Delayed Job doesn't seem to suit me as it, well, delays the job. I want to kick off a job every 5 minutes on my Rails app. Is this possible on Heroku?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a combination of their [Free Daily Cron](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron) and the above mentioned DelayedJob scheduling.  Once a day, kick off all the delayed job tasks (if you're doing 5 minute intervals, you'd need 288 jobs) to get through the day, and space them accordingly.

Edit: You don't actually need the above mentioned module.  From [this](http://www.gregbenedict.com/2009/08/19/is-delayed-job-run_at-datetime-giving-you-fits/) blog post, you can do the following

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue PollTwitter.new(), 0, 1.minutes.from_now.getutc
```

Which sets a `run_at` flag in DelayedJob.  Apparently, that's the time at which the job will be run.

Answer (score 0):

In [this blog post](http://terrbear.org/?p=230) you can find a module to add some scheduling on DelayedJob.

```
module Jobs
  module ScheduledJob
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    def perform_with_schedule
      Delayed::Job.enqueue self, 0, self.class.schedule.from_now.getutc
      perform_without_schedule
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def method_added(name)
        if name.to_s == "perform" && !@redefined
          @redefined = true
          alias_method_chain :perform, :schedule
        end
      end

      def schedule
        @schedule
      end

      def run_every(time)
        @schedule = time
      end  
    end

  end
end
```

I am using this on one of my projects, works ok!

Answer (score 0):

As of recently, you can the scheduling gem, [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork). Heroku officially supports this and you can find their documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby).